# has_no_e() exercise from Think Python

Tags: python, filter

This is from Think Python. Trying to go through each line(One word in each line) of a file and only printing out every word that does not contain the letter e.
I've spend like 4 hours trying different ways to filter the file through my function, but i give in. It seems it that it only filter out the first e it finds in a word: if a word has two e's than it prints it out anyways.

```
def has_no_e():
    file_name = raw_input('Enter the full path and file name: ') 
    fin = open(file_name)   
    line = fin.readline()

    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        print word
        for letter in word:
            if letter == 'e':
                continue
            print word




    has_no_e()
```

My code is indented btw, i think it messes up when i ctrl + v

If there's a way to make it my code shorter please let me know :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not 'e' in line: print line.strip()
```

Some comments:

- use with when working with files, although it's a newer construct in python, it helps you to manage your files (i.e. closing it again when not needed anymore)
- `word = line.strip()` makes your code not very readable. Use `line = line.strip()` (you will only use either `line` or `word`, not both, I assume)

So why was your code not working?

```
for letter in word:
    if letter == 'e':
        continue
    print word
```

Here you split the word into its letters, then you check if the letter is equal to `e`. If that's not the case, you print the word, otherwise you jump to the next letter. So you print the word as many times as there are letters different from 'e'.

A way to solve this would be to define a boolean, which tells you if there was an e in the word:

```
hasE = False
for letter in word:
    if letter == 'e':
        hasE = True
        break
if not hasE: print word
```

Note that Python also has a fancy way to solve problems like this:

```
for letter in word:
    if letter == 'e': break
else:
    print word
```

Comment: Sweet thanks! Mind explaining why my code wasn't working though?

Comment: Thanks you. The boolean example helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pfnuesel went over the main reason the code wasn't working when he wrote:

> "Here you split the word into its letters, then you check if the
>   letter is equal to e. If that's not the case, you print the word,
>   otherwise you jump to the next letter. So you print the word as many
>   times as there are letters different from 'e'."

Here's the way I solved exercise 9.2 in Think Python:

```
def has_no_e(word):
    return "e" not in word

fin = open('words.txt')

for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    if has_no_e(word):
        print word
```